# Show this holomorphic function is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a holomorphic function $f$ defined on a neighborhood of the closed unit square.

Further $f(z+i)-f(z)$ is real and not negative on $[0,1]$ and $f(z+1)-f(z)$ is real and not negative on $[0,i]$.

How do I show that $f$ is constant?

Comment: What does Cauchy's integral theorem tell you about $f$?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Compute
$$
\int_\gamma f(z)\,\mathrm{d}z=-\int_0^1\overbrace{(f(x+i)-f(x))}^{\text{real and not negative}}\,\mathrm{d}x+i\int_0^1\overbrace{(f(ix+1)-f(ix))}^{\text{real and not negative}}\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
where $\gamma$ is the square $[0,1]\cup1+[0,i]\cup i+[1,0]\cup[i,0]$.

Comment: I do not understand the notation for your parameterization of the square $\gamma$. Can you please help clarify that for me?

Comment: $[0,1]$ is the straight line from $0$ to $1$, $1+[0,i]$ is the straight line from $1$ to $1+i$, $i+[1,0]$ is the straight line from $1+i$ to $i$ and $[i,0]$ is the straight line from $i$ to $0$. Put them together and you get a unit square.